# elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse [ad_audience:targeting:8:targeting_value]')

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

Please see the partial json file below:

```
'audience': {
                'targeting': {
                    '8': {
                        'updated_at': '2012-03-05T19:55:08Z',
                        'targeting_value': 'deals',
                        'id': 'aiiy',
                        'line_item_id': '1569',
                        'account_id': 'xxxx',
                        'deleted': False,
                        'created_at': '2012-03-05T19:55:08Z',
                        'name': 'deals',
                        'targeting_type': 'UNORDERED_KEYWORD'
                    },
                    '2': {
                        'updated_at': '2012-03-05T19:55:08Z',
                        'targeting_value': 'money',
                        'id': 'aiis',
                        'line_item_id': '1569',
                        'account_id': 'yyyyy',
                        'deleted': False,
                        'created_at': '2012-03-05T19:55:08Z',
                        'name': 'money',
                        'targeting_type': 'UNORDERED_KEYWORD'
                    }
```

Above is part of json file when I try to insert complete json in elasticsearch I get as below. any help.

```
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse [ad_audience:targeting:8:targeting_value]')
```

Comment: Whats mapping for index?

Comment: sorry I am new to ES didnt get your question properly. could you please explain a bit more

Comment: belowi is dynamic mapping "ad_meta:twitter:audience:targeting:8:targeting_value" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },